# How can I store favourites for a user account?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a recipe app where users can search for recipes based on an ingredient (recipes are in the form of JSON). I have a working login and registration feature using a MySQL database (on a server) and webservices. I have implemented a login session so that the login page will only appear if the user has not logged in yet. If the user is logged in then the user can access their account settings and favourites list.

I now have a recipe page with a favourites button on the action bar. When clicked, the recipe details should be saved into the user's profile, which can be accessed and viewed from the favourites list. I have used SharedPreferences for login sessions, but can I still use it to store favourites for a user profile?

So what I mean is if I have a user called "test123" and he adds a recipe to his favourites, will SharedPreferences store this recipe for user "test123"?

**SessionManager.java**

```
public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Login";

    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();

        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
    }
}
```

**RecipePage.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.favourites:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Added to favourites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

**Favourites.java** - (fragment_favs is a listview)

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favs, container, false);

        session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

        if(!session.isLoggedIn()){
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new Login());
            ft.commit();
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Alternatively I was thinking of saving it to the MySQL database but I'm not sure if this is a more efficient method.

What solution could I have to add a favourite to a user profile?

Comment: Store it in a database via the server. SharedPreferences are not meant for large amounts of data. And you should have that information accessible from the server that way they can log in from another device and still have access to it.

Comment: @chRyNaN Are there any tutorials that I can follow to help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [android preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html):

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs_name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putString("deficitPercentage_key", prefVal); //
editor.commit();
```

the prefVal is the json, so you can latter convert that json into a pojo (serialize and deserialize)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same pojo class and save it to a file . One can avoid db if the intention is just to locally store the object .

However if you want to unfavourite the account you will need to modify the favourite list .In this case you should go for database.